# What Star Wars footage shot for one film was reused in a later film?

Tags: star-wars

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186490/ben-kenobis-other-house/186491#186491) included a clip of a deleted scene from *Return of the Jedi*.  I has seen the deleted scene before, but I noticed this time that it included a brief shot of Vader sitting in his pressure sphere, which was almost certainly taken from footage that was originally shot for *The Empire Strikes Back*.

This set me wondering what other footage was reused.  The other obvious example that immediately came to mind was the footage of the DEATH STAR firing controllers that was shot for *A New Hope* and appeared in *Return of the Jedi*.  Compare the original sequence of firing on Alderaan:

with the sequence in *Jedi* (at 1:23).

Similarly, the first poster for *Revenge of the Jedi* clearly shows a scene from *Empire*, with Luke and Vader battling in the Cloud City freezing chamber.

So are there other examples of this reuse?  As in the first case listed above, it's still interesting even if the reused footage did not make it into the final cut.

My personal interest is primarily in the original versions of the first trilogy of films, but if there are example from other films in the series, feel free to post them.  It would also not be surprising if footage were reused in lower-budget television programs, like the *Star Wars Holiday Special* or *The Ewok Adventure*.  As noted in the comments, the *Holiday Special* has lots of obvious footage from *A New Hope*, particularly of Han and Chewie in the Millennium Falcon cockpit.

Comment: Unseen footage from Star Wars made it into Rogue One.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The Star Wars Holiday Special reused footage from A New Hope.

Comment: @JackBNimble I wasn't primarily interested in lower budget things like the Holiday Special and The Ewok Adventure, but I've edited to question to address them.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the examples given in the question, we have the following, in chronological order of release:

*The Star Wars Holiday Special* uses footage from *A New Hope,* most notably this deleted scene:

*Rogue One* [uses unused footage of X-Wing pilots](https://www.slashfilm.com/old-star-wars-footage-in-rogue-one/) from *A New Hope* as well.

*Rise of Skywalker* [utilized deleted scenes](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/movies/story/2019-12-20/star-wars-rise-of-skywalker-leia-carrie-fisher-brother) from *the Force Awakens* due to Carrie Fisher's unfortunate passing.

Comment: The Special Edition of Empire Strikes Back featured an alternate take from Jedi (in Empire, it's the scene where Vader lands his shuttle on the Star Destroyer, using an alternate take/angle of the opening scene of Return of the Jedi